# how to get data from existing mongo collection using parse server?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I am new to Parse Server.

I am having an existing collection "users" in "employee" db in Mongodb.

I need to get the users data using Parse Server.

Below is the code:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(users);
query.find().then((data) => {
  return data;
}).catch((error) =>  {
  return error;
});
```

But I am getting the error "users" is not defined.

Need some valuable help.

Comment: I understand that these collections were not created using Parse, right? Parse was not designed to work with pre-existing data, but only with the data created via Parse. I'd try to can create a new class on Parse and import the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

if your Class really is called `users` (which is different to the built-in Parse Server Class called `User`), then use :

`var query = new Parse.Query('users');` //note the quotation around 'users'

If you are in fact trying to query the built-in `User` class, use :

`var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);`

or

`var query = new Parse.Query('_User');`